# How to post several answers in a row with context.PostAsync()?

Tags: botframework

I'm playing around with Microsoft's botframework. So far everything seems to work just fine, but I am unable to post several answers in one go.

I tried several context.PostAsync() calls with both text/string and Message as arguments. In those cases only the first post will be shown at the emulator, the second answer is swallowed silently.

I would like to answer some queries quickly before following up with a detailed response later.

Thanks in advance,
    Robert

Comment: I've tried using context.PostAsync() and directly with connector.Messages.SendMessage(). Neither seems to work. Actually it might be an issue with the Bot Emulator because it does seem to work with Skype and Slack connectors.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I can get it to send 3 messages back, but the 4th one fails with 500 internal server error

Comment: I also get this problem in the emulator. The second `PostAsync` gets a 401 AccessDenied exception.

Answer (score 2):

I havent tested this, since I am away from dev machine, but maybe this helps:http://docs.botframework.com/connector/replying/#multiple-replies (see Replying to the message later and Multiple replies).

Answer (score 0):

I write console application to test the bot framework code, when use PostAsync(msg) more than once before the dialog suspended, it will throw an exception **"ChannelId" cannot be null**, which means it uses "Channel" - Connector Client to send the message asynchronously.